# Почему vite.config.mts бесконечно плодится?

Tags: typescript, vite

Почему-то, когда я переименовал файл vite.config.ts в vite.config.mts (согласно документации vite '.ts' уже устарело) у меня vite.config начал бесконечно плодится после каждого перезапуска

[image: 1]

Comment: Похоже, что [это бага](https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/13267)